Does unzip have a way to extract only a specific subfolder without creating that folder's parent dirs?
I want to extract a specific subfolder (and all its contents) from a .zip using the standard unzip tool. I am not interested in its parent directories and don't want them to be created.
For example:
unzip /path/to/archive.zip "var/www/html/example.com/*" -d ~/website
I would like the ~/website folder to contain only the contents of example.com from the archive but in reality, unzip recreates the folder's parent directory path so I actually end up with ~/website/var/www/html/example.com.
I saw this question about extracting a specific folder but it did not answer this question.

No, that's not a feature that unzip has. (I just had to read man unzip to check, you should do that, too!)
You can call unzip with -l to first get a list of files within the archive, filter them with grep for the subdirectory you want, then loop over the result to call unzip to extract each individual file with the -c option to output them on stdout and write them to the target directory exactly as you wanted.
That, or, you know, you do one mv after the extraction.

You can always use libarchive's  bsdtar instead which does support extracting zip and many other archive formats and lets you edit the paths of the files upon extraction using sed/pax like s/regex/replacement/:
cd &&
  bsdtar -'s:^var/www/html/example\.com:website:' \
         -xf /path/to/archive.zip var/www/html/example.com

As an alternative, perl's Archive::Zip module has a extractTree("subdir", "target") that can be used exactly for that:
perl -MArchive::Zip -se '
  $z = Archive::Zip->new;
  $z->read($archive);
  $z->extractTree($subdir, $extract_dir)
  ' -- -archive=/path/to/archive.zip \
        -subdir=var/www/html/example.com \
   -extract_dir="$HOME/website"

If var/www/html/example.com has no file in sub-directories, you can also use the -j option of InfoZIP's unzip utility which extracts the files without leading directory components, flattening the directory structure as in Unzip file contents, but without creating archive folder:
cd && unzip -j -d website /path/to/archive.zip 'var/www/html/example.com/*'


you saving the day using bsdtar becomes a bit of a pattern…

@MarcusMüller It's been becoming for a while now :-). I'm using it for most of my archive file operations these days, replacing GNU tar, unzip and more.

Thanks. I'd love to use bsdtar but am limited by an enterprise environment.

@Clanape, yet, you managed to install unzip a MS-DOS-like utility?!

@Clanape it's very likely that getting bsdtar is no problem at all. Even statically linked, it's pretty tiny, and it's really at the backbone of many things, so not an unusual requirement at al.

@MarcusMüller, bsdtar is just a CLI interface (one of them, see also bsdcpio and bsdcat usually shipped alongside it) to libarchive, which is likely already installed. libarchive itself also has a few dependencies (many of them quite core so would likely be already installed if libarchive wasn't)

@StéphaneChazelas absolutely, but I remember having built a static bsdtar binary quite a while back for a machine that was offline and needed to unpack .tar.zst and was surprised how small the executable was that I had to burn onto a CD-ROM (yes, a few years back)

(note that it was not so long ago that CDs were still common. It was just an old machine that needed to build rsync so that I could back it up sensibly.)
